# Django: In a ModelManager, how do I access a constant defined inside the related Model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-managers

I have, for example, an Enum defined inside a Model.
That model uses, and therefore imports, a ModeLManager.

In that ModelManager, I'd like to access the Enum that I defined inside the Model; but I can't import the Model there or I'd get a circular dependency error.

An example of the issue:

Managers.py

```
class CardManager(models.Manager):
    def spades(self):
        return self.filter(suit=2)
```

Models.py

```
from foo.managers import CardManager

class Card(models.Model):

    class Suit(models.IntegerChoices):
        DIAMOND = 1
        SPADE = 2
        HEART = 3
        CLUB = 4

    suit = models.IntegerField(choices=Suit.choices)
    objects = CardManager()
```

This code works perfectly well, but instead of having `suit=2`, I'd prefer to have something like `suit=Card.Suit.SPADE`. I can't find a way to make that reference work, though, as I can't import `Card` into Managers.py.

Should I be defining the enum inside the ModelManager instead of the Model? All examples I've come across define them in the Model instead.

Comment: I ended up defining a `QuerySet` in the models.py file and using it in the Manager via `from_queryset()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your manager directly in `models.py` or outsource your suit choices to another module e.g. `choices.py`.